# how to convert utf-8 to utf-16 with ndash?

Tags: php, encoding

both:

```
$result = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', $str);
```

and `mb_convert_encoding()` fail to convert a ndash (–) the long minus.

The result will go into a csv, so replacing it with an html entity is not an option.
Any ideas?

code:

```php
            $data = $eventHelper->getProgramForCsvExport($event);

            $response = new StreamedResponse();
            $response->setCharset('UTF-16LE');
            $filename = 'program-' . $event->getShortName() . $event->getShortYear() . '.csv';

            $utf16Data = [];
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $utf16row = [];
               foreach ($row as $entry) {
                   $utf16row[] = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', $entry);
               }
                $utf16Data[] = $utf16row;

            }

            $response->setCallback(function () use ($utf16Data) {
                $output = fopen('php://output', 'w+');

                foreach ($utf16Data as $row) {
                    fputcsv($output, $row, ';');
                }

                fclose($output);
            });

            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-16');
            $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');

            return $response;
```

Edit: It's an export for the great office 365 which doesn't support UTF-8 anymore but is on UTF-16LE on default (as far as I read).
German umlauts (äöüß) work fine (and didn't before the convert), but ndash (and maybe some other special chars) don't. Ndashes are either blank (on mac) or become brackets (or so) on windows.

Comment: Looking at the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv), I can't see why you'd need both `//IGNORE` and `//TRANSLIT`. In fact, I can't see why you'd need *either* of them. There are literally no characters that can be encoded in UTF-8 but not in UTF-16. All transformation formats can encode the full range of Unicode ([source](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)).

Comment: Whatever the problem is, I don't think it's in the `iconv` call above. Make sure your result is served with the correct HTTP content type header (e.g., `Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-16`). At that point, if there's still a problem, it's in whatever is using the response (or the input string isn't in UTF-8).

Comment: Updated this post with full code. the ndash is removed when reading the csv on mac or shows some strange brackets or so on windows.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder //TRANSLIT tries to replace a not found char with a similar one. //IGNORE surpresses errors. As the ndash doesn't work I tried TRANSLIT - didn't work either. Putting IGNORE into it is I think a good idea in general if you don't want to throw exceptions.

Comment: I read the documentation. My point is that neither of them applies to a UTF-8 to UTF-16 conversion, because there are no "not found char".

Comment: Ok, but they don't hurt either and are not the problem.

Comment: I didn't say they were. But specifying pointless options isn't best practice. As someone reading the code, I have to guess at what you're trying to do.

Comment: (Sorry, "pointless" sounds a lot harsher when I read it back than I meant it. :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your code isn't outputting a UTF-16LE BOM (byte order mark) at the beginning of the file, so the programs reading it don't know what encoding it's in and are (apparently) guessing poorly.

A UTF-16LE BOM is the byte sequence `0xFF` `0xFE` (in that order) right at the beginning of the file. Make that the first thing you write to your output. More about BOMs in [this Unicode FAQ](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

To test my theory, I wrote the byte sequence for a UTF-16LE file containing *only* the characters `0–0`:

```
FF FE 30 00 13 20 30 00
```

The `FF FE` is the BOM, the `30 00` is the digit zero, the `13 20` is the N-dash, and the final `30 00` is the final digit zero. (The zeros are just there so I can easily find the dash, though in such a short file it wouldn't really be difficult.)

I was able to open that with Office 365 on Windows just fine.

Then I wrote a file without the BOM:

```
30 00 13 20 30 00
```

Office 365 did indeed misinterpret the N-dash and show it as a character that looks like a pair of brackets.

Comment: Sounds like the solution. I'll test it tomorrow to mark it as the accepted answer. And yea, didn't think of the BOM as it usually just causes trouble instead of solving it ;).

Comment: @bibamann - :-) Yeah, that tends to be the case for UTF-8 (sadly), but for UTF-16 and -32 it's helpful for the byte order.

Comment: Well the BOM was an important part to get it working. But I had to create a tmp csv in UTF-8 (tab separated!), convert it to utf-16le and put the BOM in front of it. Now it looks good in office 365. other ways (setting sep=;\n) or directly creating the csv in utf-16 either resulted in: bom was not accepted, bom was read well, but office couldn't parse it as a csv or chinese letters (when I tried fputcsv() directly as utf-16). Maybe there's a more elegant solution - but it works and I'll never touch it again! ;)